# Difference between OR and UNION ALL in this case

Tags: mysql, sql, union-all, or-operator

I've 3 entities or tables: `BOOK`, `SCIENCE` and `FICTION`. `SCIENCE` and `FICTION` are connected to `BOOK` through a foreign key called `ISBN`. `BOOK` contains also another field called `AUTHOR`.

I would like to select all authors whose book is either science or fiction. If two book have the same author, I should keep both records.

I came up with the following solution (which isn't right apparently):

```
SELECT BOOK.AUTHOR AS AUTHOR FROM BOOK, FICTION, SCIENCE
WHERE BOOK.ISBN = FICTION.ISBN OR BOOK.ISBN = SCIENCE.ISBN;
```

But the correct one should be:

```
SELECT BOOK.AUTHOR AS AUTHOR FROM BOOK, FICTION
WHERE BOOK.ISBN = FICTION.ISBN
UNION ALL
SELECT BOOK.AUTHOR AS AUTHOR FROM BOOK, SCIENCE
WHERE BOOK.ISBN = SCIENCE.ISBN;
```

Indeed they produce different results. My query returns a lot more records. What's wrong with my query? What's the difference between my query and the "correct" query below it?

Comment: Cartesian product: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join -- the first query is cross joining all the tables together.

Comment: @ps2goat But why is it doing it?

Comment: I think the design here is a little bit suspect. The `Fiction` and `Science` entities should be an attribute value of `Book` entity, named, `Genre` for example.

Comment: Both a bad problem and a bad solution.  Why would you want to list authors multiple times in a result set?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think that the purpose of the exercise was just to learn how to use certain operators or certain constructs...

Comment: @nbro . . . Still returning a result set with duplicates is generally not good.  Even worse is presenting a solution with commas in the `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 0):

There query is not wrong the OR query produce all the instance if there are similar rows the union select produce  only one Instance ..

The OR query return the relation result  .. the union return an set-theoretical results

Answer (score 0):

In the first query, if a Book's ISBN matches a Fiction ISBN, then **all** Science records are joined, and vice versa if a Science ISBN matches, then **all** Fiction records are joined.

Comment: But why should it do it? Shouldn't my query just indicate to return all book's authors provided that the two conditions are met?

Comment: I think that the problem is related to the fact that I'm saying `..FROM BOOK, FICTION, SCIENCE...`, that is, I'm saying from 3 entities, but usually we only say from 2, like in the solution...what do you think?

Comment: The conditions meet - either, or. A join without a condition is called "cartesian product": a table with n records joined with a table with m records results in n * m records. A WHERE condition just filters the result set. In your case, you get (n * m1 + n * m2) records

Comment: but where am I doing a join?

Comment: `FROM table COMMA table` means `FROM table [CROSS] JOIN table` where CROSS JOIN is the cartesian product

Comment: Ok. But what's then the meaning for example `SELECT BOOK.AUTHOR AS AUTHOR FROM BOOK, FICTION WHERE...` (i.e., the first part of the other query) if `BOOK` and `FICTION` have different fields? What's that query going to return?

Comment: The "problem" is the OR: if the 1st condition matches, the 2nd condition is ignored, therefore all records from the 2nd table are joined. If you only join 2 tables, there is no OR, therefore no CROSS JOIN